# How to run an android application using Wifi Direct (Wi-Fi peer-to-peer Wifi P2P) with Genymotion?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, genymotion, wifip2p

I see a lot of questions about running Wifi Direct applications for android on the emulator but it seems this is not possible at the moment. Then my best bet was to run it through GenyMotion VMs in the hope that I could test it this way as I dont have 2 devices ready at hand at the moment.

I have installed it, installed several platforms with various versions of Android and configurations but none of the have the Wifi-Direct option visible when I navigate into the Wifi menu. Is this a known issue or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know Direct Wifi is not supported by computer's wifi chips. So it is not possible to do real Direct Wifi on Genymotion.

Also, there is no Direct Wifi simulation ready for the tool, so for now it is not possible to use apps that uses that feature. It is not exclude that it arrives in the future but not right now.

*Disclaimer: I'm part of the Genymotion team*